# Макеты для компонентной верстки на Vue/React/Angular

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vue.js, figma

Доброго времени суток!

Хотелось бы сверстать пару макетов для портфолио на Vue, но возникли проблемы с поиском этих самых макетов.
Есть ли у вас какие-нибудь подходящие под компонентную верстку макетов или ссылки на источник откуда их можно взять?

Comment: Вы хотите взять готовые макеты и выдать их как "сделано своими руками"?

Comment: Как я могу выдать мною сверстанный макет за "сделано своими руками"? Я ищу МАКЕТ, чтобы  самому сверстать его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как по мне один из лучших сайтов (потому что сам обучался на них) для обучения верстания хоть на фреймворках хоть на нативном `HTML/CSS/JS`

Сам сайт: https://www.os-templates.com/free-basic-html5-templates

Там есть куча макетов как под резиновую вёрстку так и под PixelPerfect. На сайте лишь макеты для будущего сайта, т.е. без контента так что чего-то эпического там явно не будет. Подход в макетах почти всегда компонентый

Comment: Спасибо большое!